# Using Linq and C#, on having the min of a list AND another value at the same time

Tags: c#, linq

Having the following C# linq query:

```
var result =
    from member in members
    let BestPriceLength =
        (from lumber in lumbers
        where member.Thickness == lumber.Thickness && member.Width == lumber.Width && member.Length <= lumber.Length
        select lumber).Min(l => l.Price / l.Length)
            let BestLengthFromBestPrice = ??????
    select new 
        {
            Member = member,
            MemberLength = member.Length,
            BestLengthFromBestPrice ,
            Ratio = member.Length / BestLengthFromBestPrice,
        };
```

I don't know how to get the lumber's length chosen by for the BestPriceLength variable into the other parts of the result.

Anyone with a clever idea?

Comment: Verify the type of BestPriceLength :)

Comment: Oh, how awful, LINQ surprise. Consider OrderBy an First in place of Min.

Comment: @pst: Could you elaborate in an answer? I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done, after some hints from ***pst*** left in the comments (too bad he did not leave an answer I could accept!):

```
var result =
        from member in members
        let bestLumber =
                (from lumber in lumbers
                where member.Thickness == lumber.Thickness && member.Width == lumber.Width && member.Length <= lumber.Length
                orderby lumber.Price / (decimal)lumber.Length
                select lumber).First()
        select new 
                {
                        Member = member,
                        MemberLength = member.Length,
                        BestLumber = bestLumber,
                        Ratio = member.Length / bestLumber.Length,
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
from member in members
  let theLumber=
   (from lumber in lumbers
    where member.Thickness == lumber.Thickness && member.Width == lumber.Width &&
    member.Length <= lumber.Length
    select lumber)
  let BestPriceLength = theLumber.Min(l => l.Price / l.Length)
  let BestLengthFromBestPrice = theLumber.Length
  //etc...
```

Comment: Is it optimal? I'm worried that using theLumber in two places would iterate the list twice... Am I right in assuming that?

Comment: theLumber is obtained only once, then cached and used in the other two "let" statements.